# R: Finding help for classes created by packages

Tags: r, class, code-documentation, help-system

It often seems to be the case that R packages contain multiple functions that create an object of some `class`, specified by the package, with generic or non-generic `methods` that apply to all objects of that class. Although it is generally easy to find out about the functions in a package, I have not found any equally straightforward way to find a precise description of the `class` itself for S3 classes. I think this is at least partly intentional. Class definitions  may be regarded as the sort of internal workings that, on one hand, the user should not have to think about, and on the other, may be changeable by the package creator, who wants people not to rely on them.

However, I find that I sometimes want to create additional objects of the same `class` that work with the package functions that are methods for that `class`. And it is not always easy to deduce what features an object must have in order to be usable by package functions that do various things to objects of that `class`, especially as instances created by different functions may or may not all have exactly the same structure.

The example with which I am currently wrestling are `forecast` objects created by various functions of the `forecast` package. The forecast package provides a large number of functions that take forecast objects as inputs. [This blog post](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/) by Rob Hyndman describes a function to do cross validation and requires an object of class `forecast` as an argument  The `tsCV` function documentation says it takes a "forecastFunction" as an argument, which must return an object of class `forecast` and have a univariate time series as its first object (of forecasts, one assumes) and have an argument `h` giving the horizon. Well, that sounds easy enough. But then in Hyndman’s associated textbook, [section 3.6](https://otexts.com/fpp2/the-forecast-package-in-r.html), we are told that forecast objects contain information about the forecasting method, the data, the point forecasts, prediction intervals, residuals, and fitted values.  That’s a lot of things, and I am not sure if they are all mandatory or if some are optional, or required only if you intend to use certain methods. And I don’t know anything about mandatory internal structure of the class.

Finally, I particularly want to know if the new fable package, intended as a forecast package replacement, uses the same forecast class mechanism and require the same internal structure., or if not, how they are different. I have not been able to find, in [fpp3](https://otexts.com/fpp3/) or elsewhere, anything that either describes a change or contains a comparable description of objects of `class forecast`.

I’m going to be embarrassed if there is some simple function,

`you_should_know_this_dummy(package = “forecast”, class = “forecast”)`,

that returns a detailed description of the class. But I have looked  for such a function every way I could think of and not found it.

Comment: I think the nearest you could come is to `dput` or `str` an object of the class. R certainly does not enforce S3 class documentation, and in fact the line of code `z <- structure(list(x = 1, y = 2), class = "blah")` creates a one-off object of a new S3 class that has no nice description anywhere.

Comment: There is no formal requirement to document S3 classes so nothing is enforced. Each package designer can do whatever they like so there will be no consistent way that works for all packages and classes. So it's impossible to answer the question in the general sense. If the package author doesn't provide documentation, be best you can do is reverse engineer but that's potentially fragile. Perhaps contact the developer to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

O.K., my bad. I was trying so hard to find a way of locating the help file for the class description (which I don't think exists) that I overlooked the existence of a pretty good description of the `class forecast` under the function `forecast()` in the manual for the package `forecast`. Here it is:

```
An object of class "forecast" is a list usually containing at least the following elements:
model     A list containing information about the fitted model
method    The name of the forecasting method as a character string
mean      Point forecasts as a time series
lower     Lower limits for prediction intervals
upper     Upper limits for prediction intervals
level     The confidence values associated with the prediction intervals
x         The original time series (either object itself or the time series used to create the model stored as object).
residuals  Residuals from the fitted model. For models with additive errors, the residuals will be x minus the fitted values.
fitted    Fitted values (one-step forecasts)
```

This still leaves some questions unanswered, like the format for the model information argument `model`, and for the `x` argument with multivariate models. But I am hoping that these are similar to those handed to or returned by, e.g., `lm()`. I think this gives me enough to get started and to hope for informative errors.

I still don't know if the `fable` package also uses objects of `class forecast`. The `forecast` package documents the `forecast()` function as a generic. The `fable` package does not document the generic, though it has a very similar list of functions that look like `methods`, e.g., `forecast.whatever`. If I figure out the answer, I'll post it here.

I am also looking for a number of other package that provide time series forecast of particular types. I'm hoping that they provide output similar enough that I can use the forecast/fable functions for display, cross-validation, and so forth. We'll see.